# Converting Time and Day in User Time Zone using SQL

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, mysqli

I want to convert the Time as per User timeZone and then Displaying the day as well.
e.g. If a office opens in Chicago(US) from 8:00 am-5:00 pm  'Mon-Fri' and if the same information a user want to see in India the time must display as  8:30pm- 5:30am 'Mon-Sat' as the 5:30am comes in next day i.e Saturday as there is difference of 12.30 hrs
For this I am trying to write one store procedure that is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TimeZoneTest 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @OffSet int ,
    @tzAdjust int ,
    @BranchID int=985

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Select top 10 starttime ,endtime ,dateadd(mi, @OffSet, dateadd(hh, @tzAdjust, starttime)) as userstarttime,dateadd(mi, @OffSet, dateadd(hh, @tzAdjust, endtime)) as userendtime 
    from branchhours where  branchid = @BranchID

END
GO
```

In this SP I am passing the parameter as offset of the User Country and other as per requirement.Here the table that m using is from my database.

Comment: How are you going to get 12 1/2 hours from an integer? Or are you passing hours and minutes to adjust? Not sure what the usage is for this but an inline table valued function may prove to be more useful than a procedure since it is just a single select statement.

Comment: I am able to convert the time as per user TimeZone i.e If User Time in Chicago is 8:00am then user sitting in Singapore wud see it as 9:00PM.

Comment: but now i will have to convert the day as well.e.g. if there is 8:00 pm Friday in Chicago then the same would be in Singapore as 9:00 am Saturday so day gets changed